# Getting "ActiveX controls could not be instantiated. Reinstall or register the controls and try again" message when viewing Dialog

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, mfc, activex

I have an existing Visual C++ project using MFC that I'm running within Visual Studio 2008.  The machine was just setup and installed and I have pulled the project from Source Control.  The solution builds ok, but if I go into the resource file and try to pull up and view a dialog, I get the message

`2 ActiveX controls could not be instantiated. Reinstall or register the controls and try again message when viewing Dialog`

I'm not sure how to determine which ActiveX controls it is complaining about so I can try to re-register them since it will not display the dialog.

I am able to create a new Dialog and place controls on it, but the existing ones will not pull up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look in the .rc file of your project with a text editor.  You'll see something like this:

```
CONTROL "",IDC_MUMBLE,"{CA8A9780-280D-11CF-A24D-444553540000}",WS_TABSTOP,58,46,130,48
```

Note the GUID in braces.  Fire up regedit.exe on your old machine and navigate to `HKCR\CLSID\{guid}`.  There will be enough hints there to find the component you need install.  The InprocServer32 key points to the DLL.